# Shortest distance from a point to a set of points

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

For our classes we use a **very** old book that doesn't have any examples and my professor isn't making it any any easier for me to understand.

So my question is about the shortest distance from a point (1,-1,1) to the set of points given by z=xy.

Now I did my research online but I can't really find anything that would fully explain to me how I am supposed to do this step by step.

And no I don't have any solution since I'm not sure how to begin.

Comment: What do you know? Do you know how to find the normal vector of a surface? Do you know what Lagrange multipliers are?

Comment: @bubba I do know about the lagrange multipliers!

Comment: Take a point $(x,y,z)$ of the paraboloide hyperbolic $z=xy$ and write the expression of the distance of $(1,-1,1)$ to this point. You have to minimize this distance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a starting point: suppose that point $P = (x, y, z)$ lies on the surface. Then you know that $z = xy$, so the point is really just $(x, y, xy)$. And every point on the sruface has this form for some $x$ and $y$.

The distance from $(1, -1, 1)$ to $P$ is minimized when the SQUARED distance is minimized (this just simplifies the algebra a little). That squared distance is

$$
s(x, y) = (1 - x)^2 + (-1 - y)^2 + (1 - xy)^2.
$$

Now you have a function on the $xy$ plane, namely $s$, that you need to minimize. Go for it!

Answer (score 1):

The squared distance from $(1,-1,1)$ to the point $(x,y,z)$ is 
$(x-1)^2 + (y+1)^2 + (z-1)^2$. You need to minimize this distance subject to the constraint $z-xy = 0$. Now apply what you know about Lagrange multipliers.

We use the constraint to force the point $(x,y,z)$ to lie on the surface, since those are the only points we're interested in.